# REST verb for relation in loopback

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, loopbackjs

I have two models Post and Tag. I want to add an **existent** tag to a post (i want to relate them)
If i do `POST /post/:id/tags` it doesn't work because it **creates a new tag** associated with the post.

what would be the verb ? im i missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

There's lots of ways to do this, so your mileage may vary.

The way I see this is that you have (potentially) the following existing resources:

```
/post/1234
/tag/travel
```

Then you describe a third resource:

```
/post/1234
```

In this third resource, there are references to tag resources. This third resource *might* look like this when doing a GET request.

```
{
   tags: [
      '/tags/hobbies',
   ]
}
```

But we want to add the 'travel' tag. The way I see this, is that you *update* the tags resource to contain this new reference.

```
PUT /post/1234/tags

{
   tags: [
      '/tags/hobbies',
      '/tags/weather'
   ]
}
```

Comment: is this loopback notation ? seems like spring data rest to me

Comment: @justatester Your question sounded like a generic REST api design question, not specific to some implementation. It sounds like I misunderstood.